# Chart js: wrap legend label

Tags: reactjs, charts

chart js how can I wrap legend labels text if there is more content?

[image]

code sandbox: [legend maxline](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-clarke-pbcnsm)

`chart.js`: 3.6.0

`react-chartjs-2`: 4.3.1

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63213608/7785337 .

Comment: thanks for ans but this option is not available in the chart version `3.6.0`.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one possible solution specifically for chartjs as chartjs does not support what you are asking.

you should extract label from data object like this

```
const limit = 10;
const suffix = "..";
const labels = [
  "Redssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss",
  "Blue",
  "Yellow",
  "Green",
  "Purple",
  "Orange"
];

data.labels = labels.map((text) =>
  text.length < limit ? text : text.substring(0, limit) + suffix
);
```

It is not ideal. but this small hack can solve your problem. the problem is that tooltip will also get truncated which ideally is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks! @Robokishan for your valuable Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set overall width. For example:

```
<Doughnut
  options={{
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: "right",
        maxWidth: 120, //add this line to limit width
        labels: {
          boxWidth: 20
        }
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Chart.js Doughnut Chart"
      }
    }
  }}
  data={data}
/>
```

Comment: it's legend `width` what if i display legend in two `columns`.